# Can passport control know that I have already entered the country, if I do so with a different passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps, eu-citizens, biometric-passports

let’s say I am asking for a friend. My friend wants to enter country X with his Italian passport. He has already entered that country once previously, around 10 years ago, however with a different citizenship. He has since obtained an Italian one.

Would passport control instantly see the link between those two passports and know it’s the same person in spite of the different citizenship?

Comment: "this person has been here before" is not actually a super important piece of information to most countries on arrival. Perhaps for getting a visa, but you don't mention visas. Is there a reason you  would prefer this visit be considered a first-ever? Perhaps a problem on a previous visit?

Comment: Any answer would depend on which country 'X' is, since not all countries retain that information. The Schengen countries, presently, do not. Others do.

Comment: The question suggests that there's more to the story than so far disclosed. Might Country X be interested in the person who previously entered? Perhaps the friend is or was involved in a domestic County X police matter. If so (or similar), Country X's passport control might check other databases, not just one for persons who previously entered Country X.

Comment: Yes and the check in the other databases would be based on the name and personal data and less on the details of the previous passport.

Comment: As others have said, this is highly variable. Some will know immediately because all foreigners have their biometrics taken (fingerprints, pictures…). Others don’t have any records except stamps in passports. Many are somewhere in between, use bio data (name, date of birth…). Also some have started to record things at various dates, and others may have limits on how long they keep records (which may be different for regular visitors and those who had issues). So without details of the country and the issue you are trying to avoid, hard to give any meaningful answer…

Comment: One thing to consider, if it is relevant, is that if the person is wanted by the police for a criminal matter then they will be casting a wider net. People often report being sent to secondary inspection because police are looking for someone who has a _similar_ name, let alone the same name and the same date and place of birth.  If they're interested in the traveler because of a previous immigration violation then they are likely to make a match, but perhaps less likely than for a criminal violation.

Comment: We get a lot of questions like "will government authority X know if I do Y".  Although in principle the question can be answered, the generic answer is almost always: If you *want* them to know, you should tell them; don't assume that they necessarily have the information available.  If you *don't* want them to know, you can't safely assume that they won't find out.  Even if it's not information they *routinely* track, it's very likely possible to get it if they have a particular reason to do so.

Answer (score 3):

This is the reason why passports tend to include family name (and optionally name at birth), given name, date of birth, and place of birth. The assumption is that the combination of all four is unique and permanent, unlike citizenship which may change.

There are plenty of reports about people whose information produces a match or near-match to someone on a watchlist, and who needed to go through extra checks at immigration.